# Is it possible to put data into the action atribute without JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/employee/_here_should_be_the_value_of_the_emp_id_input" method="get">
        <label for="employeeId">Id:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="emp_id"/>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to submit the form such that the requsted `URI` will be depend on what user type into the `input`? I mean, without writing `JavaScript` explicitly, only via `HTML`.

Comment: you can use server side languages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not possible.

With jQuery it can go like this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  var input = $('#emp_id');
  input.change(function () {
    $('#form').attr('action', '/employee/' + input.val());
  });
});
</script>

<form id="form" action="/employee/_here_should_be_the_value_of_the_emp_id_input" method="get">
        <label for="employeeId">Id:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="emp_id"/>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you propose a quick solution to do that with jQuery?

Comment: thats a different question

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that without JavaScript

Comment: How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: There you have not enough fragments of the code and details of your final goal to tell how you should do in that case

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of the `action` attribute with HTML, but you *can* make the request URL (URI) depend on user input. (It is unclear which of these you are asking, but I presume you meant to ask the latter.) In fact, this happens automatically when using `method=get` (the default), when you assign a `name` attribute to an `input` element inside the form:

```
<form action="/employee/" method="get">
        <label for="emp_id">Id:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="emp_id" name="emp_id"/>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If this form appears on a page in domain www.example.com accessed with HTTP and if the user input is 42, this will generate the request URL `http://www.example.com/employee/?emp_id=42`. It is then up the server at www.example.com to take it from there.

You cannot do this without having a query part in the URL, beginning with `?`. If you need to generate a request URL of a specific format, say `http://www.example.com/employee/42` where `42` is the user input and if you cannot or don’t want to use JavaScript, you need a relay service that accepts a query URL as input and transforms, in a rather trivial way, it to the desired format and sends the request via HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 0):

With plain inline js:

```
<form id="form" oninput="document.getElementById('form').action = '/employee/' + document.getElementById('emp_id').value" action="/employee/_here_should_be_the_value_of_the_emp_id_input" method="get">
        <label for="employeeId">Id:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="emp_id"/>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The question says “without JS”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i know, but question is tagged Javascript and in the end he asks for a js solution.